# A basic question about sum of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be a two subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that sum $A + B$  is not the whole of $V$.
Then, can we say that there must exist a non zero vector $w$, orthogonal to every vector of subspace $(A+B)$?

I am proving a theorem where I have to use this result. I need confirmation.

Thanks

Comment: Are these inner product spaces?

Comment: @William not inner product space

Comment: To speak of othogonality you must have more than just a vector space.  Do you mean that $V$ is an inner product space?  If so, this is true if and only if $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: @srijan If you talk of orthogonality, you need an inner product.

Comment: @srijan: What can "orthogonal" *possibly* mean without an inner product?

Comment: What does the sum stuff have to do with the problem?

Comment: I am sorry it should be inner product space.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making valuable comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a finite dimensional inner product vector space, yes, because for every subspace $W$ we have $(W^{\perp})^{\perp} = W$. In particular, if $W\neq V$, then $W^{\perp}\neq\mathbf{0}$, since $\mathbf{0}^{\perp}=V$. That $W$ is a sum is immaterial.

In the infinite dimensional case, no. You can have a proper subspace whose orthogonal complement is trivial. E.g., in the vector space of all square summable real sequences, viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, the span of the basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_i$ is a proper subspace that is dense, so its orthogonal complement is trivial. The same holds in any infinite dimensional Hilbert space, by taking the span of a Hilbert basis.

*Added.* If your space does not have an inner product, then the very concept of "orthogonality" has no meaning, so the answer is [Mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29#Signifying_.22unasking.22_the_question_or_similar).